# Most efficient way to process arguments from the command-line in C++

Tags: c++, windows

Suggestions for **command-line argument** processing in C++ efficiently:

**Note**: Windows specific only

```
 1:     #include <iostream.h>
 2:     int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Instead of, for example:

```
 if ( argc != 3 )  {
      ....
 }
```

Regards